# Registering an application for the Microsoft Graph API in the German National Cloud

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online

I have successfully registered my application for `graph.microsoft.com`, but now it also needs to work with `graph.cloudapi.de`.

The [Application Registration Portal](https://apps.dev.microsoft.com) does not seem to be the correct one for the German National Cloud.

Moreover, applications registered in `portal.microsoftazure.de` only work with the SharePoint API, not Graph.

Here's a sample HTTP exchange between my program and the German Microsoft Cloud. I am hand coding HTTP requests in Delphi. The exchange works with graph.microsoft.com, but not graph.microsoft.de.

I start the authentication via the following https URL:

`login.microsoftonline.de/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=xyz&prompt=login&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.de%2Fuser.read%20&response_mode=query&state=5736109994698155204&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.syncovery.com%2Foauthresult.php`

The cloud then directs to my redirect URL with a long code parameter, such as

```
code=AQABAAIAAQDnLpu3ikefR73l_aNlxt5xxdvNhQ9JVAI7b0ciTej............
```

So far, so good. Now the hard part:

```http
POST /common/oauth2/v2.0/token HTTP/1.1 
Host: login.microsoftonline.de 
Keep-Alive: 300 
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded 
Content-Length: 805

client_id=xyz&client_secret=abc&code=AQABAAIAAQD_very_long&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.xyz.com%2Foauthresult.php&grant_type=authorization_code&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.de%2Fuser.read%20
```

Reply:

```http
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Expires: -1
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
x-ms-request-id: e83986c0-5da4-4af7-92fc-46e2fb950100
P3P: CP="DSP CUR OTPi IND OTRi ONL FIN"
Set-Cookie: esctx=AQABAAAAA_longish domain=.login.microsoftonline.de; path=/; secure; HttpOnly
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Wed, 07 Feb 2018 11:11:44 GMT
Content-Length: 449

{
    "error": "invalid_client",
    "error_description": "AADSTS70002: Error validating credentials. AADSTS50012: Invalid client secret is provided.\r\nTrace ID: e83986c0-5da4-4af7-92fc-46e2fb950100\r\nCorrelation ID: 044f44e3-ec09-4f76-b073-0ff6b72b696a\r\nTimestamp: 2018-02-07 11:11:45Z",
    "error_codes": [70002, 50012],
    "timestamp": "2018-02-07 11:11:45Z",
    "trace_id": "e83986c0-5da4-4af7-92fc-46e2fb950100",
    "correlation_id": "044f44e3-ec09-4f76-b073-0ff6b72b696a"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `apps.dev.microsoft.com` portal is global, there isn't a national cloud instance of the portal. You do however need to register your app under an AAD account using "Azure AD only applications" rather than "Converged applications". This is because the v2 Endpoint itself isn't supported by national cloud endpoints yet.

Another problem here is that your URI is also incorrect.

Some notes from the [documentation](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/deployments#microsoft-graph-and-microsoft-graph-explorer-service-root-endpoints) related to Germany:

- Microsoft Graph Root Endpoint: `https://graph.microsoft.de` (not `graph.cloudapi.de`)
- OAuth2.0 Endpoint: `https://login.microsoftonline.de`
- The Azure AD v2.0 authorization and token endpoints are available on the global service only; they are not yet supported for use with national cloud deployments.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! So the same application ID and secret should work with both the global and the German national cloud? When I use my application with the German cloud, I now get this error: AADSTS90092: Non-retryable error has occurred. Trace ID: c70c9297-7031-4e9d-83f9-e15e8f350100 Correlation ID: 7f58b2bf-7fe5-4815-b0f8-d26191c8e3d7

Comment: Now I don't get this error any more, maybe it was an intermittent server problem. But now it says "invalid client secret provided". The German cloud does not seem to accept the secrets from the global app registration portal.

Comment: Could you edit your original question and  add the authorization URL and the code you're using?

Comment: Thanks, I included all the details, maybe you can spot the problem.

Comment: *face palm* I should have read your question closer, I'm so sorry. To clarify, `apps.dev.microsoft.com` is fine but "Converged applications" (v2) are not. You need to sign in to `apps.dev.microsoft.com` using an AAD account and create this as an "Azure AD only applications" (v1).

Comment: Hello,
thanks! No I'm getting much further. My main problem was that I thought that Graph required the new V2 authentication. I did not see the "Plus" button in the Azure portal where new APIs can be added to an app.