# Authenticating User to use the graph api in the german national cloud

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I have an application that uses the following scopes to access data in Microsoft Graph:

```
[
 'openid',
 'offline_access',
 'email',
 'profile',
 'https://graph.microsoft.com/Mail.ReadWrite',
 'https://graph.microsoft.com/Mail.Send',
 'https://graph.microsoft.com/User.Read',
 'https://graph.microsoft.com/Contacts.ReadWrite',
 'https://graph.microsoft.com/Calendars.ReadWrite'
]
```

I am using [passport-oauth](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-oauth2) in my node application for authentication.
It works perfectly fine for Office 365 emails of different companies but it doesn't work for German domains (e.g. `abc@abc.onmicrosoft.de`).

I already tried solutions specified in [Registering an application for the Microsoft Graph API in the German National Cloud](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48641159/registering-an-application-for-the-microsoft-graph-api-in-the-german-national-cl)

with `graph.microsoft.de` as the Microsoft Graph URI and `login.microsoft.de` as the authorization endpoint.

Currently, the app I am using is registered on `apps.dev.microsoft.com`.

I get this error when I try to login with my german o365 account

> TokenError: AADSTS90043: Confidential Client is not supported in Cross Cloud request.

My question is where do I register an app that works for all German O365 instances since the app needs to support multiple domain accounts.
I tried authenticating with 
The authorize url that results in invalid client secret error is as follows

```
https://login.microsoftonline.de/common/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A1345%2Fauthorize&scope=openid%20offline_access%20email%20profile%20https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.de%2FMail.ReadWrite%20https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.de%2FMail.Send%20https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.de%2FUser.Read%20https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.de%2FContacts.ReadWrite%20https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.de%2FCalendars.ReadWrite&state=key%3Dlocal-dt&client_id=7beb27dd-805c-47e5-bbb4-639a3e41a9dd
```

Answer (score 2):

The `apps.dev.microsoft.com` portal is a Global registration for "Converged" app authentication (i.e. the v2 Endpoint that support both AAD and personal MSA accounts). This v2 Endpoint isn't supported by [National cloud deployments](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/deployments) at the moment.

From the [documentation](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/deployments#azure-ad-openid-connect-and-oauth20-endpoints):

> **Note:** The Azure AD v2.0 authorization and token endpoints are available on the global service only; they are not yet supported for use with national cloud deployments.

In order to have an application that works with both Global and National Cloud Endpoint, you need to use the v1 Endpoint. This is done via an Azure AD portal rather than `apps.dev.microsoft.com`.

---

The Authorization URI you're navigating too has the correct v1 Endpoint URL (`https://login.microsoftonline.de/common/oauth2/authorize`) but you're providing v2 Endpoint query parameters:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.de/common/oauth2/authorize
?response_type=code
&redirect_uri=http://localhost:1345/authorize
&scope=openid offline_access email profile https://graph.microsoft.de/Mail.ReadWrite https://graph.microsoft.de/Mail.Send https://graph.microsoft.de/User.Read https://graph.microsoft.de/Contacts.ReadWrite https://graph.microsoft.de/Calendars.ReadWrite
&state=key=local-dt
&client_id=7beb27dd-805c-47e5-bbb4-639a3e41a9dd
```

The v1 Endpoint doesn't support dynamic scopes. Instead, scopes are defined by your Application Registration via the Azure Portal.

Your URL prototype should look like this:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.de/common/oauth2/authorize?
client_id=7beb27dd-805c-47e5-bbb4-639a3e41a9dd
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A1345%2Fauthorize
&response_mode=query
&state=key=key%3Dlocal-dt
```

Comment: I tried creating an app in azure active directory.
If i use that app I get the following error:
AADSTS90130: Application '7beb27dd-805c-47e5-bbb4-639a3e41a9dd' (testing) is not supported over the /common or /consumers endpoints. Please use the /organizations or tenant-specific endpoint.

Comment: The above error is with multi-tenanted set to yes. If i set multi tenanted to no I get this error:

Comment: AADSTS70001: Application with identifier '7beb27dd-805c-47e5-bbb4' was not found in the directory 9f02abcd-7b81-45d8-8afd

Comment: You need to use `/organizations` instead of `/common` in your Auth URI:  `https://login.microsoftonline.de/organizations/oauth2/authorize`. This tells it to exclude consumer MSA accounts.

Comment: AADSTS90002: Tenant organinizations not found. This may happen if there are no active subscriptions for the tenant. Check with your subscription administrator.

Comment: Interesting. Returning to `common`, are you using `https://login.microsoftonline.de/common/oauth2/authorize` or `https://login.microsoftonline.de/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize`?

Comment: tried both https://login.microsoftonline.de/organizations/oauth2/authorize and https://login.microsoftonline.de/organizations/oauth2/v2.0/authorize , I get the tenenat not found error

Comment: I tried again with https://login.microsoftonline.de/common/oauth2/authorize

Comment: I get 500 response from the api, AADSTS70002: Error validating credentials. AADSTS50012: Invalid client secret is provided.

Comment: Can you add the full URI you're using to your original question? You shouldn't be sending a secret to the `/authorize` endpoint.

Comment: well i am using passport oauth2. so when i setup the passport strategy i define the client secret. 
the authorize url that i see in the browser is :

Comment: https://login.microsoftonline.de/common/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A1345%2Fauthorize&scope=openid%20offline_access%20email%20profile%20https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.de%2FMail.ReadWrite%20https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.de%2FMail.Send%20https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.de%2FUser.Read%20https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.de%2FContacts.ReadWrite%20https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.de%2FCalendars.ReadWrite&state=key%3Dlocal-dt&client_id=7beb27dd-805c-47e5-bbb4-639a3e41a9dd

Comment: So i thought there might be a problem with my setup of paasport so i tried using https://github.com/AzureADQuickStarts/WebApp-OpenIDConnect-NodeJS

Comment: If i set the identity metadata to https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/.well-known/openid-configuration, it works perfectly fine

Comment: But if i change it to https://login.microsoftonline.de/common/.well-known/openid-configuration it fails. In the console logs i see

Comment: the url that is called is https://login.microsoftonline.de/common/oauth2/authorize?redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fauth%2Fopenid%2Freturn&response_type=code&response_mode=query&client_id=7beb27dd-805c-47e5-bbb4-639a3e41a9dd&state=br1P0s1ldgefeM4Ztl2lqARt9YaxkYfo&nonce=iBEKs0tVLSbaSHeCSdWnrNyiBwMAs7FZ&x-client-SKU=passport-azure-ad&x-client-Ver=3.0.12

Comment: 2018-04-03T08:12:06.426Z]  INFO: AzureAD: OIDC Passport Strategy/5846 on MacBook-Pro.local: entering Strategy.prototype._authCodeFlowHandler
[2018-04-03T08:12:06.427Z]  INFO: AzureAD: OIDC Passport Strategy/5846 on MacBook-Pro.local: In _getAccessTokenBySecretOrAssertion: we are using client secret
[2018-04-03T08:12:07.543Z]  INFO: AzureAD: OIDC Passport Strategy/5846 on MacBook-Pro.local: authentication failed due to: In _authCodeFlowHandler: failed to redeem authorization code

Comment: ::1 - - [03/Apr/2018:08:12:07 +0000] "GET /auth/openid/return?code=AQABAAIAAQDnLpu3ikefR73l_aNlxt5xIgCEJlHLsg-kBawBFVS0IAryEBSbLIGBmHrcQv6Q_vE1zIc729duHcGCjyDbD3MnQAKLSxdUjBWO_i6bJG2v_nPVq_3Tn1FXCYGCCKLHl8KYAOYXKXztGVqsLnW5H70CgyBXJPaemHb26I2gd8xiFLLMMTLSj7hu9OtmlITcyINNatoFLBPXGySxPVSwgCAXW9HdQn4SG39R8VPT8qjoK3QxCepz_NZGZR6FhKeMMw53vjpiwVUt5pa9qmlJNSe9vvFx1civefDwP4CemwUEovEt0efq8eFsMFUJktzMgprPgvdlrhw87s1AVOVMscj1lkiwv2sOFnoktnd1rA_GUP8o7emWzytL8MD2GtOsMrtykrhEHe3sHkmZunpUi2p7QLW_wmqiqguJ5UoIXRX_Ij1E1XDQiuLCgUrhrXuZTmx4XYdR2O7p1jYp-cCxgp3TVqiR2_5Gi3SEx_ai2np1Oqk5Yo2vEX36PpGjHNuaSmiZmGiSkj

Comment: You're requesting OpenID Connect elements without requesting an `id_token` in the `response_type`. See this [documentation for instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-protocols-openid-connect-code) on OpenID with the v1 Endpoint

Comment: So it turns out the problem was that i needed to create an aad app for an azure account on the .de domain.

Comment: Thanks for the help!